# CoreAnimation: CALayer Blending Mode

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, blending

What's the best way to get blending (e.g. additive) between two `CALayers` (e.g. two `CAShapeLayers`) to work properly and performant?

This is for `CALayers` that have animated content, like `CAShapeLayers` with changing shapes.